# Why did Veronica ensure that her husband saw her drinking from the flask?

Tags: plot-explanation, widows

In *Widows* (2018), Veronica went to her husband, who was taking a shower, to show him that she had drank from the flask:

[image]

Why did Veronica ensure that her husband saw her drinking from the flask?